# Show url variable message on a page

Tags: php, forms, url, controller, get

I have a form page with a authController for validation.
Here is the code of the form page:

```
<div class="main-content">
    <h3>log in as student</h3>
    <h3>
        <!-- SHOW URL MESSAGE HERE -->
    </h3>
    <form action="../app/controllers/authController.php" class="login_form" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="" class="input_field">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="" class="input_field">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="type" id="" value="Log In" class="btn btn-info">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the code form the authController:

```
if ($_POST['type'] == 'Log In') {

    if (! Validator::notEmpty()->validate($_POST['username']) || 
        ! Validator::notEmpty()->validate($_POST['password'])) {

        $err_msg = "One of the fields is empty";
        $user->redirect('stu_login.php?type=' . $err_msg);
        exit;
    }
```

How do i show the `$err_msg` that is defined in the authController, on the form page where the `<!-- SHOW URL MESSAGE HERE -->` is?

Comment: which framework?

Comment: Why don't you try AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$user->redirect('stu_login.php?type=' . $err_msg);
```

To

```
$user->redirect('stu_login.php?msg=' . $err_msg);
```

And use in stu_login.php like this

```
<h3>
    <!-- ERROR OR OTHER MESSAGE -->
    <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['msg'] != '') 
           echo $_GET['msg']; 
    ?> 
</h3>
```

Comment: or simply `if(isset($_GET['type'] != '')` ?!!

Comment: I do not prefer to use same variable name as submit button name. It's a message so, relevant name would be better.

Comment: i mean that this is not the prober way to do, both `msg` or `type` or anything else , specially that the OP had not provided fair details about his env;

Comment: Yes you are right this is the minimum solution we can suggest

Comment: @MayaShah I tried that and i get this error message when i load the form page: `Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in C:\wamp64\www\Websites\CapitoWonen\public_html\stu_login.php on line 6`

Comment: Strange!! use as suggested. <?php if(null !== $_GET['msg']) { echo $_GET['msg]; } ?> and check if you get any issue with and without msg varible in url